# asp net looping through server control in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, servercontrol

I am developing a web page using asp net web forms.

In javascript I can loop through my components;

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
     $("#textbox" + i).get(0).style.display = 'none';
}
```

However when I set runat="server" for components, I need to access;

```
$("#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>").get(0).style.display = 'none';
$("#<%=textbox2.ClientID %>").get(0).style.display = 'none';
```

My question is, is there a way to loop through components which are set runat="server" in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign cssClass to the elements. That class names will not change while rendering.

Then you can use `$(".classname").hide()` to hide all the elements with a particular class name.

You can loop them as well

```
$(".classname") each(function () {
    $(this).get(0)//if you need dom element
});
```